# A method for linking a server side file to a Squarespace page?

Tags: server, backend, squarespace

I'm trying to build a website on Squarespace, in which the site links to a database file. It's stored in a standard file system on a server tower with cluster. No SQL architecture or anything that I explicitly know of. Unfortunately Google Drive isn't an option due to the size of the file ( > 200 GB). I'm rather lost due to the size constraint -- does anyone have an idea about how to do this? Can I set up some sort of server query using a link on the site? Can I upload the file from my computer and store it somewhere in the backend? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"...the size of the file ( > 200 GB)..."*

Unfortunately, Squarespace's own upload limitations are far below this for the two places where files like that can be stored: file storage ([20MB](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/206542517-Formatting-your-images-for-display-on-the-web&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwif452tlJ7rAhWShK0KHVpfBeQQFjALegQICBAB&usg=AOvVaw1AI_g2P5fvrFjmG9ZkQjpT)) and developer-mode '/assets' folder ([10MB](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://developers.squarespace.com/template-overview&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwif452tlJ7rAhWShK0KHVpfBeQQFjAJegQIChAB&usg=AOvVaw2eGiANBx9g6taOeI5NB8Zl)). The CSS-/Style-related storage only supports images (and likely has a limit of less than 20MB). Digital download products [can be 300MB](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/206540787-Digital-products&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwif452tlJ7rAhWShK0KHVpfBeQQFjAQegQIAhAB&usg=AOvVaw3rqpt7U2So8JDbpzjAsvhG) (still to small for your file) and likely can't be linked-to and accessed as you'd need for your application.

*"...Can I set up some sort of server query using a link on the site?..."*

If you mean a query on some other service besides Squarespace which connects to the file hosted on your Squarespace site, the answer is no simply because there's no way to upload the file to Squarespace due to its size. If, however, your mean a query from your Squarespace site to the file hosted elsewhere, then this must be done using JavaScript and done entirely client-side due to [Squarespace's lack of support for server-side languages](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/205815358-Custom-code-FAQ).

*"...Can I upload the file from my computer and store it somewhere in the backend?..."*

See the options mentioned above, though all have file size limits below that of your file.

If you are able to utilize the file on your site using client-size/front-end JavaScript only, then perhaps you could host the file on Amazon S3 or other such provider and access it that way.